# How add move up/down element to list editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

In editor for list exists context menu inclides items - dublicate array element,
delete array element.

How add move down/up element in list to Editor?

Comment: Ok. I'll answer here too :D I don't think it's possible. You can use custom editor for your property though. You can try this one: bitbucket.org/rotorz/reorderable-list-editor-field-for-unity

Comment: Tried that bitbucket link, but the script did not render custom objects properly.